VB6 - Tratando resposta da TextBox para Digitação do usuario
Um Salve para Todos, sou novo Aqui e no VB6, Tenho na TextBox com uma resposta numériaca pre determinada no programa, quando a resposta e mais de 1 digito no TextBox, o programa determina que é falsa a resposta, e está correto. só que gostaria que o usuário termine de digitar para o programa começar executar a leitura da TextBox. exemplo.
TextBox2 = "2+9"
Resposta do usuario.
quando digita 1 o programa já executa como errado e mostra a MsgBox de Erro.
Ou seja a TextBox não aguarda a digitação completa do 11.
Tem Solução? fico no Aguardo, já agradecendo a todos.
Private Sub Text2_Change()

  If Text2.Text <> "40" Then
    MsgBox "Tente de Novo, Você Errou"
    Text2.SetFocus
  End If

  If Text2.Text = "40" Then MsgBox "Voce Acertou, Passou, Aperte o enter para ir pra proxima"
    
  If Text3.Locked = True Then Text3.Locked = False
  End If
End Sub


Coloque seu código na pergunta para facilitar a resposta.

Ok, Agradeço a Observação, vou acrescentar, Valeu.

Se a resposta deve ter mais de um digito então você faz a seguinte verificação no início:
If len(Text2.Text) < 2 Then Exit sub Obs se está entrando agora no mundo da programação recomendo aprender linguagens mais atuais, Python por exemplo.
